# what's the difference between sudo -H pip install and sudo pip install

Tags: python, sudo, pip

when I do `sudo pip3 install numpy`, terminal show that:

```
The directory '/home/tiger/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/tiger/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

It recommend me to do `sudo -H` instead, terminal didn't show anything warning after I typed `sudo -H pip3 install matplotlib`.

I type `man sudo`, it show that:

```
-H, --set-home
Request that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to the home directory specified by the target user's password database entry.  Depending on the policy, this may be the default behavior.
```

But `pip3 show numpy` and `pip3 install matplotlib` both show that `Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`.
So what's the difference between `sudo -H pip install` and `sudo pip install`?

Comment: A similar question is answered in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623025/what-does-sudo-h-do